# Set TextBox Text to special value from Mater Page class

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, set, master-pages

So I have Web Forms project in Visual Studio with Master page. It the `Add.aspx`  I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:textBox runat="server" ID="surname" CssClass="textbox"></asp:textBox>
    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
</div>
```

I want to set text in this TextBox from Master Page. In `Add.aspx.cs` I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
public void SetSurname(String value)
{
    this.surname.Text = value;
}
```

And at `Site.Master.cs` I am trying to call `SetSurname` to set it to special value:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add AddForm = new Add();
    AddForm.SetSurname("Test");
}
```

But I am getting error: `Object reference does not point to an instance of an object` pointing to `this.surname.Text = value;`. Am I wrong somewhere? Mabye I should use some functions like `Page_Afterload` or etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understant correctly, the `TextBox` `surename` exists only in `Add.aspx`. If so, you won't be able to call the method `SetSurname()` from anywhere else except inside of `Add.aspx`, because there is no guarantee the the Control `surename` exists in the current showing page.
Also, the line `Add AddForm = new Add();` is meaningless, unless you use it somewhere else in the code. If you want to use `SetSurname()`, you should do that from the `Page_Load()` of `Add.aspx`.

If I got the wohle thing wrong please notify me.